# How to spoof referer while submitting a simple html form?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome-extension, submit, spoofing

I need to submit the form to domain-A
However, my webpage is located at domain-B

domain-A will only accept input from it's own website,
is there any way to trick it for my request to go through?

I've been already doing this for Ajax requests with google chrome extension on before send headers listener.

But what do I do if it is just a simple html form?
Is it even doable in JavaScript?

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is place a cross site request. Most sites will take at least some basic steps to prevent this. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Comment: If you are going to use Chrome Extensions, you could:
1) Insert a content_script on your page that gets the input.
2) Content_script sends data to background.
3) You change the page to domain-A
4) You insert a content_script on domain-A
5) Background sends a call to script and changes the form values for the stored ones.
6) Submits form.

Comment: fvbuendia I could of course, but this will make two http requests to server A. 1st request to load the webpage and 2nd request to submit the form. And I only need to make one request :)